# React.JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at findLoader

Tags: reactjs

I am working on following a tutorial (https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/react-tutorial-cloning-yelp/#routing) on making a yelp clone using react.JS. I keep encountering the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
>       at findLoader

The error is occuring in my webpack.config.js file, and isn't allowing me to run the program or establish a connection to my localhost.

```js
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const join = path.join;
const resolve = path.resolve;

const getConfig = require('hjs-webpack');

const isDev = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isTest = NODE_ENV === 'test';

// devServer config
const devHost   = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const devPort   = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const setPublicPath = process.env.SET_PUBLIC_PATH !== 'false';
const publicPath  = (isDev && setPublicPath) ? `//${devHost}:${devPort}/` : '';

const root = resolve(__dirname);
const src = join(root, 'src');
const modules = join(root, 'node_modules');
const dest = join(root, 'dist');
const css = join(src, 'styles');

var config = getConfig({
  isDev: isDev || isTest,
  in: join(src, 'app.js'),
  out: dest,
  html: function (context) {
    return {
      'index.html': context.defaultTemplate({
        title: 'FoodFinder',
        publicPath,
        meta: {}
      })
    };
  }
});

// ENV variables
const dotEnvVars = dotenv.config();
const environmentEnv = dotenv.config({
  path: join(root, 'config', `${NODE_ENV}.config.js`),
  silent: true
});
const envVariables =
    Object.assign({}, dotEnvVars, environmentEnv);

const defines =
  Object.keys(envVariables)
  .reduce((memo, key) => {
    const val = JSON.stringify(envVariables[key]);
    memo[`__${key.toUpperCase()}__`] = val;
    return memo;
  }, {
    __NODE_ENV__: JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
    __DEBUG__: isDev
  });

config.plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(defines)
].concat(config.plugins);
// END ENV variables

// CSS modules
const cssModulesNames = `${isDev ? '[path][name]__[local]__' : ''}[hash:base64:5]`;

const matchCssLoaders = /(^|!)(css-loader)($|!)/;

const findLoader = (loaders, match) => {
  const found = loaders.filter(l => l && l.loader && l.loader.match(match));
  return found ? found[0] : null;
};

// existing css loader
const cssloader =
  findLoader(config.module.loaders, matchCssLoaders);

const newloader = Object.assign({}, cssloader, {
  test: /\.module\.css$/,
  include: [src],
  loader: cssloader.loader.replace(matchCssLoaders, `$1$2?modules&localIdentName=${cssModulesNames}$3`)
});
config.module.loaders.push(newloader);
cssloader.test = new RegExp(`[^module]${cssloader.test.source}`);
cssloader.loader = newloader.loader;

config.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: [modules],
  loader: 'style!css'
});

// CSS modules

// postcss
config.postcss = [].concat([
  require('precss')({}),
  require('autoprefixer')({}),
  require('cssnano')({})
]);

// END postcss

// Roots
config.resolve.root = [src, modules];
config.resolve.alias = {
  css: join(src, 'styles'),
  containers: join(src, 'containers'),
  components: join(src, 'components'),
  utils: join(src, 'utils'),
  styles: join(src, 'styles')
};
// end Roots

// Dev
if (isDev) {
  config.devServer.port = devPort;
  config.devServer.hostname = devHost;
}

// Testing
if (isTest) {
  config.externals = {
    'react/addons': true,
    'react/lib/ReactContext': true,
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true
  };

  config.module.noParse = /[/\\]sinon\.js/;
  config.resolve.alias.sinon = 'sinon/pkg/sinon';

  config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(p => {
    const name = p.constructor.toString();
    const fnName = name.match(/^function (.*)\((.*\))/);

    const idx = [
      'DedupePlugin',
      'UglifyJsPlugin'
    ].indexOf(fnName[1]);
    return idx < 0;
  });
}
// End Testing

    module.exports = config;
```

I am very new to React.JS and full stack development in general, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Tyler Sebastian will not work because `const cssloader = findLoader(...);` is used to find the existing cssloader according to the tutorial you're using, and the new loader that's being pushed is to replace it.

The error, it seems according to comments on the tutorial is that the technologies used in the tutorial have been updated which caused it to break. The suggested solution by a commenter was to delete your node_modules directory, replace the webpack.config.js file with the one provided in the tutorial repo and reinstall the dependencies (Essentially reverting to older versions of the technologies).

I do not think that is a good way to go about it since the purpose is to learn something useful not just make it work, but it should work. As I am a similarly inexperienced React dev who attempted to use this outdated tutorial, I can't come up with a better solution

EDIT: I've tried the comment suggested solution and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that you look for a loader before you "register" loaders

```js
const cssloader = findLoader(config.module.loaders, matchCssLoaders);
```

comes before uses of `config.module.loaders.push(...)`. It's hard to tell because you're initializing `config` through a function call so I'm not sure what the initial value is.

If you anticipate the type of `config.modules` to be `null | loader[]`, you can change the first line in `findLoader` to `const found = (loaders || []).filter(...)`

Also,

```js
const findLoader = (loaders, match) => {
  const found = loaders.filter(l => l && l.loader && l.loader.match(match));
  return found ? found[0] : null;
};
```

doesn't do what you think it will... consider

```js
let x = [] // an empty array
console.log(x ? "not empty" : "empty")

> "not empty"
```

it's not like Python3 where an empty array == False and `filter` always returns an array