# React: Uncaught at TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null within a property

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-props

I am rather new to React and I am supposed to debug somebody else's code. The error is

> React: Uncaught at TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null

The corresponding code snippet (within `render()`) where the error occurs is

```
 <MyTable size="small"
    dataSource={this.props.summaryData.filter(record => record.DifferenceValue !== 0 && 
                record.Value >= record.AdjustedValue) }
    rowKey={(record) => (record.Id).toString()} 
    pagination={false}
    locale={{ emptyText: 'No applicable summary data found' }}>
```

I guess, that it is not important that `Table` comes from [Antd](https://ant.design/) and `class MyTable extends Table<Interfaces.ViewEntry> { }` which is essentially an [Antd Table](https://ant.design/components/table/).

I understand that I should catch a possible `null` value of `this.props.summaryData.filter()` or of `summaryData` within the property `dataSource`. I want to have a workaround like the following pseudocode, but I am not sure about the correct syntax:

```
dataSource = {
  var out = this.props.summaryData.filter(record => record.DifferenceValue !== 0 &&
                                         record.ErdrValue >= record.AdjustedValue)
  if out = null return null else return out;
}
```

I am sure it is easy, but I just don't know the correct syntax, please help me.

### Related questions

- [React.JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at findLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079557/react-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-filter-of-undefined-at-findloader)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354704/typeerror-cannot-read-property-filter-of-undefined-in-react)

Comment: you can do something like
```this.props.summaryData && <Table ... />``` but make sure that you are passing summarydata in props

Comment: it tells that if your data is null , don't mount the <Table ... /> component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check if `summaryData` is null or not -

```
let dataSource = this.props.summaryData ? 
         this.props.summaryData.filter(record => record.DifferenceValue !== 0 && record.Value >= record.AdjustedValue):[]
```

Now `dataSource` is either empty `[]` or it is an array returned by your `filter` function.
then

```
<MyTable size="small"
    dataSource={dataSource}
    rowKey={(record) => (record.Id).toString()} 
    pagination={false}
    locale={{ emptyText: 'No applicable summary data found' }}>
```

Comment: @B--rian no put it inside your render function, before rendering `MyTable` component

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a prop value on to another component's prop. An option to fix this is to check your prop is not of null value before mounting your **MyTable** class. This in turn can be achieved through [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

**Using && operator**

You can put that straight in your **render** method.

```
this.props.summaryData &&
<MyTable size="small"
dataSource={this.props.summaryData.filter(record => record.DifferenceValue !== 0 && 
            record.Value >= record.AdjustedValue) }
rowKey={(record) => (record.Id).toString()} 
pagination={false}
locale={{ emptyText: 'No applicable summary data found' }}>
```

**With a variable and if condition**

```
let conditionalMyTable = this.props.summaryData
            ? <MyTable ... />
            : null;
```

Then wherever you were rendering `<MyTable.../>` substitute it for the variable `conditionalMyTable`.

**Due to Ant design use variables for value itself of dataSource prop**

*Option 1, place the query inside*

```
<MyTable size="small"
    dataSource={this.props.summaryData 
                ? this.props.summaryData.filter(record => 
                           record.DifferenceValue !== 0 && 
                           record.Value >= record.AdjustedValue)
                : null
               }
    rowKey={(record) => (record.Id).toString()} 
    pagination={false}
    locale={{ emptyText: 'No applicable summary data found' }}>
```

*Option 2, use an external variable*

```
let summaryData = this.props.summaryData || [];
<MyTable size="small"
dataSource={summaryData.filter(record => record.DifferenceValue !== 0 && 
            record.Value >= record.AdjustedValue) }
rowKey={(record) => (record.Id).toString()} 
pagination={false}
locale={{ emptyText: 'No applicable summary data found' }}>
```

**Another option**

Maybe the mistake is not here, this is just a symptom. Maybe you never ever want **this.props.summaryData** to ever be null or anything that is not an Array. Then I would suggest going straight to the source, [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). That would mean modifying the class that is rendering **MyTable**, and has the prop **summaryData**

```
class IRenderMyTable extends React.Component {
 ....
}

IRenderMyTable.propTypes = {
  summaryData: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

IRenderMyTable. defaultProps = {
  summaryData: []
```

};

With this new code, whoever renders the **IRenderMyTable** will either not pass any props, in which case **summaryData** would be an empty list but never null. Or they will pass something of type Array. In both scenarios you avoid the exception of trying to execute **.filter()** on a **null** value.

Awesome benefit of this? You don't have to worry about doing constant **if** questions whenever you are going to use the prop.

I love using **defaultProps** and **propTypes** to make sure whoever uses them, does it right.

Comment: Thanks for the very insightful lines. Sadly, for layout reasons, I cannot get rid of the table, but rather use `locale={{ emptyText: 'No applicable difference risk positions found' }}`, see https://ant.design/components/table/#API `emptyText`

Comment: No problem, I can add an option to that s well. Although I always advocate for the last answer, which is through propDefault and propTypes.